# Update child component value on axios response using v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Vue 3

I am trying to update the value of the data variable from the Axios response. If I print the value in the parent component it's getting printed and updates on the response but the variable's value is not updating in the child component.

What I am able to figure out is my child component is not receiving the updated values. But I don't know why is this happening.

input-field is a global component.

Vue 3

Parent Component

```
    <template>
    <input-field title="First Name" :validation="true" v-model="firstName.value" :validationMessage="firstName.validationMessage"></input-field>
</template>
<script>
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                id: 0,
                firstName: {
                    value: '',
                    validationMessage: '',
                },
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.id = this.$route.params.id;
            this.$http.get('/users/' + this.id).then(response => {
                this.firstName.value = response.data.data.firstName;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label :for="identifier">{{ title }}
            <span class="text-danger" v-if="validation">*</span>
        </label>
        <input :id="identifier" :type="type" class="form-control" :class="validationMessageClass" :placeholder="title" v-model="inputValue">
        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="validationMessage">{{ validationMessage }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            validation: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false,
                default: false,
            },
            type: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: 'text',
            },
            validationMessage: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: '',
            },
            modelValue: {
                required: false,
                default: '',
            }
        },
        emits: [
            'update:modelValue'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                inputValue: this.modelValue,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            identifier() {
                return this.title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');
            },
            validationMessageClass() {
                if (this.validationMessage) {
                    return 'is-invalid';
                }
                return false;
            }
        },
        watch: {
            inputValue() {
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken you should use `value` and not `modelValue` in child component also to emit after my knowledge the action is `input` but  think it depond on vue version

Comment: Where are you calling your child component? in your parent component I only see a input-field

Comment: @khofaai not if he is using Vue 3 (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-model.html)

Comment: @jkoestinger oops, he didn't specify the version, I assumed it is version 2... Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @jkoestinger thanks for it, i was looking to make sure, thanks

Comment: I am using the vue 3

Comment: As @Hamza said, I believe your child component is called "input-field", but I dont see it imported in the components of your parent component. You should first import child component in parent, like you would do with any library. Then create "components" option (like data, methods and computed) and define the imported child component there. Then use itas a custom tag, like you have now.

Comment: It's a global component and it's working perfectly. But the issue is it's now showing the updated value

Comment: The reason your child will never receive an update from your parent is because even if you change the firstName.value your child-component will not re-mount and realize that change.
It's bound to a property that it internally creates (inputValue) and keeps watching *that* and not the modelValue that's been passed from the top.
Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vite-starter-forked-7zxym?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) using your code and it does exactly what it's supposed to. It receives a value once (firstName.value), creates another property (inputValue) and emits that

Comment: I added another watcher that would cover the face that modelValue changes are supposed to be passed down to the inputValue property.
With that change the component should work as you wanted it to but tbh I think it's not really well made that way :D
Here's another [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vite-starter-forked-wrmy9) that uses a computed property instead to create the sort of binding you were looking for. No watchers necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your child will never receive an update from your parent is because even if you change the `firstName.value` your child-component will not re-mount and realize that change.
It's bound to a property that it internally creates (`inputValue`) and keeps watching that and not the `modelValue` that's been passed from the parent.
Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vite-starter-forked-7zxym?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) using your code and it does exactly what it's supposed to and how you would expect it to work.
It receives a value once (`firstName.value`), creates another property (`inputValue`) and emits that value when there's a change.
No matter how many times the parent changes the `firstName.value` property, the child doesn't care, it's not the property that the input v-model of the child looks at.

You can do this instead

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label :for="identifier"
      >{{ title }}
      <span class="text-danger" v-if="validation">*</span>
    </label>
    <input
      :id="identifier"
      :type="type"
      class="form-control"
      :class="validationMessageClass"
      :placeholder="title"
      v-model="localValue" // here we bind localValue as v-model to the input
    />
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="validationMessage">
      {{ validationMessage }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ... // your code
  computed: {
    localValue: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:modelValue", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

We remove the watchers and instead utilize a computed property which will return the modelValue in it's getter (so whenever the parent passes a new value we actually use **that** and not the localValue) and a setter that emits the update event to the parent.

Here's another [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vite-starter-forked-wrmy9?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-1478) example illustrating the above solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help.